# VBA scripting for MS excel

Tags: excel, vba

[Image added as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQVDZ.png)I am writing a VBA script for MS excel which involves multiple functionalities.
I am stuck at this point. Giving a rough example:-

If I have an excel having this data, I want to select those value where "man" is present(case insensitive) in the beginning/middle/last and assigning a value to those rows.

Input excel

```
Serial  Name 
1       superman
2       spiderman
3       Thor
4       Hulk
5       Captain America
6       Mandrake
```

Ouput Excel should be:

```
Serial  Name               Found man
1       superman           Hello
2       spiderman          Hello
3       Thor    
4       Hulk    
5       Captain America 
6       Mandrake           Hello
```

I want only VBA script because it involves various other complexities and functionalities. So, no Excel formulas please.

I tried using `Range.Find` function but in that I am not able to assign "Hello" to next cells.

your help will be much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you meant, the following code loops through all rows with data, and for each row checks if the word "man" is inside that strings (using the `Instr` function).

```
Sub FindMan()

Dim FindString                  As String
Dim Sht                         As Worksheet

Dim LastRow                     As Long
Dim lRow                        As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet name
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With Sht
    ' find last row in Column "B"
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' you can modify your searched word as you wish at the following line
    FindString = "man"

    ' loop through all rows with data in cells "B"
    For lRow = 2 To LastRow
        If InStr(1, .Cells(lRow, 2), FindString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = "Hello"  ' if found add "Hello" to the cell on the right > Column C
        End If
    Next lRow

    ' add header title for Column C
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Found man"    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You !!
This is what I was looking at. I got the code running with removals of dots(.). for ex:- LastRow = *removed dot here* Cells(Rows.Count, "B")....